# IntelliJ plugin handle on cmd action (go to declaration)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

For a custom IntelliJ plugin I am trying to write a handler that is invoked when the user uses the "cmd" key (or "control" in windows) and clicks in the value of an XML tag (which usually triggers a "go to declaration" or "show usages") in regular java code. In the tutorials I have found samples for creating a plugin that handles a click to an entry in the menu bar, but I need a handler for that one specific action.

Does IntelliJ support handling that event and execute a custom action? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do when the user clicks the tag name? If you need to navigate to another element, then you don't actually need to handle the click event - instead, you need to provide a `PsiReference` and return the target element from its `resolve()` method.

Comment: Ah yes, that is what I was looking for. If you can post this as a reply I can mark it.